# Maven problem with dependencies between 2 seperate projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

so I have to project having the same groupId but each with a different artifactId. The first project is called persistence and doesn't have any dependencies and the other is called core and needs to depend on persistence. I did a clean install on the persistence project and I can see it was added to my local repo (.m2 directory). In the pom of the core I can add a dependency on persistence with no problems but whenever I try to use any classes from it I can't seem to import them, the ide simply can'y find them and if I do a import cbs.... then I have a symbol not found error.

Here is the pom files:

persistence

```
<groupId>cbs</groupId>
<artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Code:

```
<groupId>cbs</groupId>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fazecast</groupId>
        <artifactId>jSerialComm</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cbs</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: You should never use `LATEST` as version it's very long deprecated. You should use version literals instead...like `1.2` for pi4j-core...

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind I just found out my packages where messed up and the java classes of persistence were totally outside the packages. So if anyone is having this issue it could be that the class you re trying to import is directly inside the src folder and not in any package.